# django-cms showing 500 internal server error while deleting plugin from admin

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-cms

I have recently started working with Django CMS. I have successfully added a plugin on the admin side, but while deleting it from the admin interface it is showing internal server error on chrome console:

Django version 1.3.2

Django CMS version 2.2

```
POST https://localhost:8000/admin/cms/page/56/remove-plugin/ 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR) jquery.min.js:130
c.extend.ajaxjquery.min.js:130
c.extend.postjquery.min.js:122
plugin_delete_click_handlerplugin_editor.js:139
c.event.handlejquery.min.js:55
c.event.add.j.handle.ojquery.min.js:49
```

Any idea why this happens? I have downgraded Django-mptt to 0.4.2 still the same persists.

Comment: What's the actual error? If you have debug enabled on your server, you can see the actual error trace in the chrome console (click the 'network' tab, then click the the 500 error and go to 'response' subtab

Comment: btw, I had a similar issue, it was regarding database migrations not having been correctly carried out (columns in the DB didn't exist)

Comment: i have checked it . btw i am getting this error for all plugin ..it seems like a script error on plugin_delete_click_handlerplugin_editor.js

Comment: It's going to be difficult to help if we can't see the actual server stacktrace/error

Comment: hi timmy i have checked it and it seems like db issue .Thanks for you r updates